# How should the Query's format be structured for sending a call with 'Greater than' condition in AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I wanted to run a greater than Query against the primary key of my table. 
Later I came to know that `greater than` queries can only be executed on `sort keys`, and not on `primary keys`. So, I have now re-designed my table, and here's a screenshot of the new it : (`StoreID` is the Primary key, & `OrderID` is the Sort key)

[image: sample table screenshot]

---

How should I format the Query, if I want to run a query like `return those items whose 'OrderID' > 1005`?
More particularly, what should I mention in the Query condition to meet my requirements?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In you primary table, it's not possible to run query "return those items whose 'OrderID' > 1005" **across all stores**. Only queries like "return those items in store with storeid='STR100' whose 'OrderID' > 1005" are possible.

Comment: Ok, That would work for me too. How should I format the query for `storeID = STR100 & orderID > 1005`? Thanks!

Comment: If you use AWS CLI, here is an example. `aws dynamodb query --table-name <table-name> --key-condition-expression "StoreID = :v1 AND OrderID > :v2" --expression-attribute-values '{":v1": {"S": "STR100"}, ":v2": {"N": 1005}}'`

Comment: Thanks @jellycsc! You have solved my problem! :) P.S. I can't find the green tick to mark your comment as answer - is it only for proper answers & not comments? Thanks!

Comment: yeah, I reposted as an answer. Please accept it if you find it helpful ◡̈

Comment: Thanks! Just marked it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following CLI command to run query "return those items in store with storeid='STR100' whose 'OrderID' > 1005".

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name <table-name> --key-condition-expression "StoreID = :v1 AND OrderID > :v2" --expression-attribute-values '{":v1": {"S": "STR100"}, ":v2": {"N": 1005}}'
```